# Why can't I upload to a blob?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-blob-storage

I'm attempting to upload data to a blob in a local blob container. I'm getting a System.IO.Exception with message

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. : 'C:\repos\{repository-name}\{solution-name}\{project-name}\bin\Debug\net6.0

followed by the data I'm attempting to upload.

This is my code:

```
public async Task UploadData(Data data, string currentSequenceNumber)
{
    // The blob container exists
    bool exists = await BlobContainerClient.ExistsAsync();
    // the blobname is 20230317142352_923.json
    string blobName = $"{dateTimeProvider.NowUtc:yyyyMMddHHmmss}_{currentSequenceNumber.PadLeft(3, '0')}.json"; 
    BlobClient blobClient = BlobContainerClient
        .GetBlobClient(blobName);
    // This serialises the data as a string with length 13770
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tennetResponse, Formatting.Indented);
    // This throws the exception
    await blobClient.UploadAsync(json);
}
```

The absolute URI of the blob is "http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/storage/data_20230317142352_923.json".

I've tried modifying the upload statement to

```
await blobClient.UploadAsync(data, new BlobUploadOptions
{
    HttpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders()
    {
        ContentType = MediaTypeNames.Application.Json
    }
});
```

With no result.

Manually uploading a file with the same name and content through Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer succeeds.

How does anyone have any idea why I'm getting this error and how to solve it?

Comment: `UploadAsync` overload accepts a string that is a path to a file and not the actual content. You could use `new BinaryData(json)` or use a stream.

Comment: @NotFound Ahhh of course. new BinaryData(json) does the trick indeed. Thank you!

(Note to self: Read summaries on methods before using them.)

Answer (score 3):

I was using the overload

```
UploadAsync(string path)
```

which expects a path, not the content. Changing my statement to

```
UploadAsync(new BinaryData(json))
```

fixes it.

(Thank you to user NotFound for pointing this out.)